# Spark RDD to Dataframe with JsValues failes with exception

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have an `RDD[(String, JsValue)]` that I would like converted to a dataframe to use SQL on.

If I define `case class Holder(s:String, j:JsValue)`, I can then do

```
val mydf = myrdd.map(x => Holder(x._1,x._2)).toDF().
```

However, if I then do mydf.schema.mkString(","), I get the following error below. Any ideas what is going on and how to fix it?

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Schema for type play.api.libs.json.JsValue is not supported
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$class.schemaFor(ScalaReflection.scala:718)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$.schemaFor(ScalaReflection.scala:30)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$$anonfun$schemaFor$1.apply(ScalaReflection.scala:693)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$$anonfun$schemaFor$1.apply(ScalaReflection.scala:691)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244)
        at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:318)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:244)
        at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.map(Traversable.scala:105)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$class.schemaFor(ScalaReflection.scala:691)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$.schemaFor(ScalaReflection.scala:30)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$class.schemaFor(ScalaReflection.scala:630)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$.schemaFor(ScalaReflection.scala:30)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext.createDataFrame(SQLContext.scala:414)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLImplicits.rddToDataFrameHolder(SQLImplicits.scala:94)
```

Comment: I think the error message is pretty clear. The analyzer doesn't know the schema for a `JsValue` base trait, which is a custom type created in Play.

Comment: Ok so how do I get the analyzer to know the schema for that type/trait?